# Radio Button Display as current Value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a radio button that act as status selector for company record.
Problem is when edit record. i want radio button in editdialog preselect according to current status of record.

current code

```js
<v-radio-group v-model="company.status" row mandatory>
   <v-radio label="Active" color="red" value="Active" />
   <v-radio label="Inactive" color="red" value="Inactive" />
</v-radio-group>
```

I've tried a solution as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563307/vuetify-radio-button-not-appearing-as-checked) and it still don't work as intend.

```js
<v-radio-group label="Status:" v-model="radioadd" row mandatory>
   <v-radio label="Active" color="red" :value="Active" key="0" />
   <v-radio label="Inactive" color="red" :value="Inactive" key="1" />
</v-radio-group>
```

this time it warn me that Active and inactive property or method is not define.

pls advise

ps. I'm pretty new to coding and *vue* (2week)

**Update**  solved

```
       <v-radio-group v-model="company.status" row>
          <v-radio label="Active" color="red" :value="'Active'"/>
          <v-radio label="Inactive" color="red" :value="'Inactive'"/>
       </v-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is mostly correct. However, the `:value` binding expects an expression, and in this case it's true that the binding cannot find a variable/property named Active or Inactive on the model. Instead, you could wrap the value bindings in quotes (because `'Active'` in JavaScript is an expression which evaluates as a string literal):

```html
<v-radio label="Active" color="red" :value="'Active'" key="0" />
```

Note the quotes around Active.

Alternatively, you can use the `literal` modifier, which tells the value binding to interpret the given value as a literal rather than an expression:

```html
<v-radio label="Active" color="red" :value.literal="Active" key="0" />
```

Whichever approach you choose, apply the same to the Inactive radio button element.

Comment: Thank! This method is work.But either i add a key prop or not.It still work So i curious what meaning of "key" prop in this. Anyway Thankyou.

Comment: The `key` attribute is a unique identifier, most commonly used in `v-for`. You can read more here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/key-attribute.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change anything with `value`. The markup you already have is correct (i.e., `value="Active"` is correct and makes the radio group's value equal to `"Active"` when this radio is selected).

To initialize the radio group to the current value of `company.status`, that property needs to equal one of the values within the radio group (i.e., `"Active"` or `"Inactive"`).

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      company: {
        status: 'Inactive' // initial value of radio group
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/binding-initial-value-of-radio-group-in-vuetify-3dhje?file=/src/components/CompanyInfo.vue:276-355)